How can I merge different resolution data attributes on QGIS?
I have 12.5m resolution DEM data for particular district. I converted raster to points for claim each point's elevation. And I also have 1km resolution avg temperature data about it. I must add avg temperature data attributes on my 12.5m resolution points. How can I do that?
I extracted them but I can't handle to merge.
